# Existe alguna forma que los botones de datatable impriman imagenes incrustadas en la tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Pues tengo una tabla que está cargada con PHP pero incluye una imagen en las columnas. El problema es que los botones de dataTables no imprime las imágenes, hay alguna forma de incluirlas?

```
 $("#example1").DataTable({
   "infoCallback": function( settings, start, end, max, total, pre ) {
     var api = this.api();
     var pageInfo = api.page.info();
     return 'Página '+ (pageInfo.page+1) +' de '+ pageInfo.pages;
   },
   "responsive": true, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
   "buttons": ["excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
}).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
```

Comment: Exactamente a que te refieres con "los botones no imprimen las imágenes"? Te refieres a que los botones deben ser imágenes? Puedes mostrar una imagen del resultado y posiblemente de lo que esperas?

Comment: Hola @MauroAguilar lamento la tardanza de mi respuesta. Me refiero a que los botones de DataTables que me exporta la tabla en excel, pdf y demás, no imprime las imagenes que tengo en mi tabla en estos archivos que exportan. Quería saber si había alguna forma que incrustrara también las imágenes.